# How to escpe the '/' character in a variable?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm currently creating directories with a variable called currentDate.

I am trying to create the following directory:

`business/bookings/15/06/2020` //3 levels down. the date is a level.

with `business/bookings/currentDate`

However, JavaScript and Firebase will interpret the '/' as another directory.

How could I solve this problem given that I'll get a variable that's always formatted this way?

Comment: Which Firebase product are you working with? There are over a dozen of them.  Please edit the question to be more clear about the problem you're trying to solve regarding a Firebase product.

Comment: Are you stating you want to store the date as *06/2020*? If so, that's problematic to start with as it won't sort correctly. You're way better off storing dates as *yyyymmdd* format like *202006*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple substitution would be with `escape`/`unescape`, but nowadays I'd probably use `encodeURIComponent`/`decodeURIComponent`:

```
encodeURIComponent("business/bookings/currentDate")
```

> "business%2Fbookings%2FcurrentDate"

```
decodeURIComponent("business%2Fbookings%2FcurrentDate")
```

> "business/bookings/currentDate"

Answer (score 1):

Short version: you can't.

The `/` character is not admitted in file (and directories) name. What you can do is to substitute the slash character with something else.

Hope this helps.